# Cannot get attribute size from File object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With input is file, I can log to console the File as

```
console.log(file.size)
```

It gives me:

```
File(3987) {name: "download.jpeg", lastModified: 1544914267262, lastModifiedDate: Sat Dec 15 2018 14:51:07 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 3987, …}
lastModified: 1544914267262
lastModifiedDate: Sat Dec 15 2018 14:51:07 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) {}
name: "download.jpeg"
size: 3987
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

However when I do `console.log(e.target.files[0].size)`

It does not even fire.

Full Code as requested. FIle is coming from `<input onChange={(e)=>{this.handChangeFile(e.target.files[0])}}/>`

```
this.handleChangeFile = (file) => {

  console.log(typeof file)


 this.setState({ thefile: file })
  let fileData = new FileReader();

  fileData.readAsDataURL(file);
  fileData.onloadend = () => {
    imageBase64 = fileData.result
    if (this.state.first == true) {
      this.setState({ binary: imageBase64, hide_stock: !this.state.hide_stock, first: false }, () => {

      })
    }
    else
      this.setState({ binary: imageBase64 }, () => {

      })
  }

}
```

Comment: if you replace wherever you have `console.log(e.target.files[0])` with `console.log(e.target.files[0].size)`, your code does not work? It's kind of hard to tell here because there isn't enough context, but I would assume you have it in the incorrect function/event handler

Comment: Hello there. Can you share the full code, please? It is hard to see the problem with looking this little code.

Comment: Well, `this.handChangeFile)e.target.files[0])` is a typo. Just in the question, or your code too?

Comment: Only in this code....

Comment: I have the same question with @Andy. Also, this is still not the full code. Share your code as much as possible, please. You don't need to pass the file directly like that in your callback function but still, it should work as it is.

Comment: Well, it seems that you are not willing to share the full code. It is too late here, so here are my thoughts. If your callback handler method isn't fired: 1. It could be a typo 2. You are using the handler in the wrong way. So, check your code, it can't be a bug. If you are not using a linter, give a chance to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on jsfiddle

with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/dqLv83zr/

with React: https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/23fv1te5/

Both they are working. Can you share your code why it is not working?

jQuery

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/dqLv83zr/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

React

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/23fv1te5/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share your code simply on jsfiddle? I will try it on React :))

Comment: @Danny.j, I also try on React and it's working, can you share your code to find the problem?

Comment: @Danny.j, where is `console.log(e.target.files[0].size)` in your code? You can see my new trying https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/23fv1te5/15/ maybe it will help you :)) Function `handleChange` should be without `this.` when be declared in React

Comment: this is just a bug there is nothing wrong with my code